# having an issue with log4net and MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, log4net

The plattform that I am using is Visual Basic 2012 and the Visual Studio professional 2012...

I have a installation of log4net in my project - the version is 1.2.13, installed via the nuGet packet manager.

By testing log4net, it seems that it is working correctly.

But since I have installed log4net all MySQL related actions are not woking any more.
I have also installed the MySQL connector via the NuGet packet manager, it is version 6.7.4

I definitely traced down the problem to be somehow related with the installation from log4net, because when I completely remove the log4net related xml from the app.config, all MySQL actions are working again as they should work.

log4net code from the app.config:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
 <root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
 </root>
 <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <file value="logfile.txt"/>
 <appendToFile value="true" />
 <rollingStyle value="Size" />
 <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
 <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
 <staticLogFileName value="true" />
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger.%M[%thread]: %message%newline"/>
 </layout>
 </appender>
</log4net>
```

log4net on the top of each class:

```
Private Shared ReadOnly log As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)
```

log4net code in the AssemblyInfo.vb:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch:=True)>
```

Example of DB QUery:

```
Private Sub btnMySQLScalarQuery_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnMySQLScalarQuery.Click

    Dim DatabaseAccessObject As New classDatabaseAccess With {.MySQLIpAdress = "10.140.140.220", .MySQLUsername = "admin", .MySQLPassword = "adminxyz", .MySQLDBName = "sensors", .ErrorMsg = True}

    Try
        Using command As New MySqlCommand
            Using connection As New MySqlConnection((DatabaseAccessObject.GetMySQLConnectionString()))
                **connection.Open()**
                command.Connection = connection
                command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wims_detections WHERE id > @start AND id < @end"
                command.Prepare()
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", 100)
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", 1000)
                connection.Close()
            End Using

            MessageBox.Show(DatabaseAccessObject.ScalarQuery(command))
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

This is the error message, that I get, when the log4net is activated due to having the code in the app.config:

**The type initializer for "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager" generated an exception.**

I am not using the ReplicationManager...! But it seams that the ReplicationManager has somehow an issue wit log4net...

The error happens in the line, where I am attemting to open the Database connection ... connection.open()

I have to note here, that I am also using SQLite in my project, tough SQLite is absolutely unaffected by this issue - even tough I have buildt the MySQL Querys / NonQuerys / Transactions the same way I have buildt that with SQLite...

Help is needed!

Kind Regards...

Comment: Do you have MySQL config in the app.config as well?

Comment: Just a heads up you did not sanitize the UN and PW from your question.

Comment: Whats the full exception?

Comment: having same issue - any resolution?